# How to convert date string to timestamp in Kotlin?

Tags: date, kotlin, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I  want to convert a date string to unix timestamp from a date string e.g. `14-02-2018`

Can someone help?

Comment: Look into using `SimpleDateFormat`, or better yet try out the Java 8 date API.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since JDK 8 you can do:

```
val l = LocalDate.parse("14-02-2018", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))

val unix = l.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().epochSecond
```

Note that the example uses your system's default timezone.

Comment: Note: 
This only work for SDK 26 and above for lower SDK follow this : https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

Answer (score 68):

use this to convert the date string to UNIX timestamp

```
val date = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("14-02-2018")
println(date.time)
```

Comment: should only be used if JDK <= 1.7 also note that the formatter is not threadsafe

Answer (score 5):

For backward compatibility use ThreeTenABP library but a better solution from Android itself will be enabling support https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

Once enabled you can now parse String date to any valid format pattern

```
LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).format(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM. dd, yyyy")
```