# Android - Convert user selected time to UTC and vice versa

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on Android application, and I want to convert user-selected local time (device time) into UTC seconds. After that, I have to convert it again and display in the device's time zone. Can anyone suggest how to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert date string to timestamp in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838992/how-to-convert-date-string-to-timestamp-in-kotlin)

Comment: @kelvin No, this is not the right ans

Comment: @Τζιότι You can try this [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to convert user-selected local time (device time) into UTC seconds

You're thinking about this incorrectly.  Timestamps, including device time, do not have a time zone.  All timestamps are seconds since Jan 1 1970 00:00 UTC, regardless of device time zone.  If the user selects a time, and you have that time as a timestamp, it's already in the right format. You can think of it as "UTC seconds," since it's based on a time in UTC, but there's no such thing as timestamps that aren't in such "UTC seconds."

The only time you need a time zone is for converting to a date, displaying it to a user, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Constructs a `SimpleDateFormat` using the given pattern and the default date format symbols for the default FORMAT locale

```
fun localToGMT(): Date? {
    val date = Date()
    val sdf = getDateInstance()
    sdf.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
    return DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse(sdf.format(date))
}
fun gmttoLocalDate(date: Date):Date? {
    val timeZone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID();
    val local = Date(date.getTime() + TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone).getOffset(date.getTime()));
    return local
}
```